# com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: query 'SELECT * FROM system.peers' timed out after PT0.5S

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, connection-timeout

I am trying to process inserts Kafka Streams aggregation results to Cassandra. But I am getting below timeout error during connection after 500ms. Why this occur and how can I increase this timeout or is it possible to turn off this query?

```
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: query 'SELECT * FROM system.peers' timed out after PT0.5S
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException.copy(DriverTimeoutException.java:34)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:149)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.build(SessionBuilder.java:612)
    at aggregator.sink.CassandraSink.connect(CassandraSink.java:94)
    at aggregator.sink.CassandraSink.init(CassandraSink.java:62)
    at aggregator.sink.CassandraSink_ClientProxy.init(CassandraSink_ClientProxy.zig:253)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$init$0(ProcessorNode.java:97)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:806)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.init(ProcessorNode.java:94)
```

**datastax-java-driver config:**

```properties
datastax-java-driver.basic.contact-points.0=10.0.111.61:9042
datastax-java-driver.basic.load-balancing-policy.local-datacenter=datacenter1
datastax-java-driver.basic.session-keyspace=my_ks
datastax-java-driver.basic.request.timeout=20 seconds
datastax-java-driver.advanced.auth-provider.class=PlainTextAuthProvider
datastax-java-driver.advanced.auth-provider.username=${CASSANDRA_USR}
datastax-java-driver.advanced.auth-provider.password=${CASSANDRA_PWD}
datastax-java-driver.advanced.protocol.version=V4
datastax-java-driver.advanced.timestamp-generator.force-java-clock=true
datastax-java-driver.advanced.connection.init-query-timeout=10000 milliseconds
datastax-java-driver.advanced.connection.pool.remote.size=10
datastax-java-driver.advanced.connection.pool.local.size=5
datastax-java-driver.advanced.heartbeat.timeout=2000 milliseconds
```

```pom
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-driver-query-builder</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Instead of the using custom code, I recommend to use DataStax Kafka Connector: https://docs.datastax.com/en/kafka/doc/index.html

Comment: Is it possible mapping user defined types?

Comment: they should be presented as subobjects of the row in Kafka

Comment: It looks good, I will try this solution. I know it is not root case, but I found from ```DefaultTopologyMonitor``` and I can increase timeout by setting ```advanced.control-connection.timeout```. Also I didn't understand why it is 500ms, I've set ```init-query-timeout=10000 milliseconds``` by reference its default value is variable ($init-query-timeout) https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.5/manual/core/configuration/reference/

Comment: @AlexOtt, there is also [Kafka Connect Cassandra](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-cassandra/) from Confluent, but I can't see any mapping config there. Is it useful?

Comment: No, Confluent's connector requires you that topic structure directly matched table structure. If it doesn't match, you need to create a new topic that matches this structure. That's why DataStax's is more flexible

Comment: @AlexOtt How do you set init-query-timeout using the DS kafka connector? I'm having a hard time finding where to put it in the `.properties` file. (I'm using Standalone mode). Is that the `datastax-java-driver config` that @nikli is referring to?

Comment: Never mind, found the answer https://docs.datastax.com/en/kafka/doc/kafka/kafkaSettingJavaDriverConfig.html

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Datastax Kafka Connector, and want to change java driver configs, you add what you have above into your `connect-standalone.properties` file (or whatever you have it named). Namespace configs with `datastax-java-driver`.

In particular, adding this to my `connect-standalone.properties` file got the timeout working for me:

```
datastax-java-driver.advanced.connection.init-query-timeout=2000 milliseconds
```

For more information, see [the official documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/kafka/doc/kafka/kafkaSettingJavaDriverConfig.html).

However, keep in mind that sometimes the real problem is not that the timeout is too low, but instead the fact that you are timing out is a symptom of a different underlying issue. See [here at Datastax community](https://community.datastax.com/questions/387/drivertimeoutexception-after-enabling-auth.html) for one discussion related to this.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to add this one as well, to avoid timeouts on `system.peers`:

`datastax-java-driver.advanced.control-connection.timeout=20000 milliseconds`